# Do I need to import a package from a jar file after setting the classpath?

Tags: java, import, classpath, plc

So here is the deal - I downloaded a jar file that I need to communicate with an Allen Bradley PLC.  Naturally I set up the CLASSPATH and expected to just be able to create a program with a constructor from one of the classes in the jar file and go about my way.  This was not the case.

Here is my CLASSPATH:

```
nick@ubuntu:~/Java/PLC Program$ echo $CLASSPATH
/home/nick/Java/PLC Program/ethernetip4j-0.2.jar
```

Here is the code in my program:

```
ControlLogixConnector test = new ControlLogixConnector(ENBTIP,44818);
```

I compile and get the following errors:

```
nick@ubuntu:~/Java/PLC Program$ javac PLCServer.java
PLCServer.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    ControlLogixConnector test = new ControlLogixConnector(ENBTIP,44818);
    ^
symbol:   class ControlLogixConnector
location: class PLCServer
PLCServer.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    ControlLogixConnector test = new ControlLogixConnector(ENBTIP,44818);
                                     ^
symbol:   class ControlLogixConnector
location: class PLCServer
2 errors
```

I have my program and jar file in the same directory.  Do I need to import any package that is in the jar file or am I missing something else completely different?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import se.opendataxchange.ethernetip4j.clx.ControlLogixConnector;

class PLCServer
{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException
    {
        // IP address of the ethernet card
        String ENBTIP = "192.168.10.14";
        ControlLogixConnector test = new ControlLogixConnector(ENBTIP,44818);
    }
}
```

I get errors saying the se.opendataexchange.ethernetip4j.clx.ControlLogixConnector doesn't exist and the ControlLogixConnector object doesn't exist (compiled with javac PLCServer.java).

Comment: You need to `import` required classes. You might want to step back and bone up on how Java works before going too much further; it may save some time.

Comment: The jar may contain several packages. Use import.

Comment: add `import se.opendataexchange.ethernetip4j.clx.ControlLogixConnector` into your PLCServer.java

Comment: I added import se.opendataexchange.ethernetip4j.clx.ControlLogixConnector; and the error still says the package doesn't exist @allergic

Comment: What command are you using for compilation? Try ... `javac -cp .;ethernetip4j-0.2.jar PLCServer.java`

Comment: javac PLCServer.java with no options @xagyg

Comment: Can you try `javac -cp .;ethernetip4j-0.2.jar PLCServer.java` and see what you get pls?

Comment: nick@ubuntu:~/Java/PLC Program$ javac -cp .;ethernetip4j-0.2.jar PLCServer.java
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
ethernetip4j-0.2.jar: command not found
@xagyg

Comment: sorry forgot you on UNIX, please replace the semicolon ";" with a colon ":". `javac -cp .:ethernetip4j-0.2.jar PLCServer.java`

Comment: After doing that I still get the errors.  @xagyg

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement `import home.nick.Java.PLCProgram.ethernetip4j.*;` seems to indicate the location of the **jar** within your project.

This is incorrect.

Instead, it is meant to reference the **package structure** of the jar, resolving to the class (or set of classes, if using a wildcard) that you are trying to use.

If you do not know which package the class `ControlLogixConnector` resides in, you can unpack the jar and it should be obvious by the the directory structure. (@allergic has pointed in comments that it is `se.opendataexchange.ethernetip4j.clx`).

You can get even more precise by decompiling the `.class` file from within the jar, using a utility like JAD, or something similar.  Importing the Jar into any IDE should do the trick, though - the classes within the jar should be broken out in a tree view by package.